# index.php file was damaged. did someone hacked me

Tags: php

Yesterday, I visited my website as a normal visitor and everything was fine, but today when I tried to do, I got this message: "Access Denied.".  So I checked it via FTP and found the index.php file damaged, and it was impossible to download it.

I don't understand this behavior? Does that make sense? is not it possible that someone has stolen my files using hacking techniques.

PS: I change my FTP password every time I finished with.

Comment: In what way was index.php impossible to download? Do you mean via FTP? Were the permissions set such that you could not get it?

Comment: Yes, before I was able to download it via FTP, but now I can't because is damaged !

Comment: You should still be able to download it, whatever state it is in. Are you absolutely sure you are unable to retrieve it via FTP? I am not asking whether you can subsequently open it, which is a different issue.

Comment: Can you give us a broad overview as to what the site is, whether it is custom-written or a standard installation (e.g. Wordpress)? At the moment we have nothing to go on. Emil is quite right - your site could have been hacked, and the question of "what is hackable" is too big a topic to do justice to in an answer here.

Comment: No I can't download it, please you can found in this [link](http://free.yudu.com/item_files/630431/afe3554e6/FTP.png) an image with the error message shown on my FTP.

It's an application made ​​by hand, that has two scripts : the first one to login into the dashbord and the second one sends a message to all adress emails in the database automatically every day (using a crontab)

Comment: OK, perhaps the permissions are wrong - as I said before. Try resetting them in FileZilla or SSH, and if that fails, ask your host to `chmod` and/or `chown`.

Answer (score 2):

Your index.php was probably overwritten by an unsafe PHP script. Check all files which handle file uploads. Control that they only allow saving into certain predefined folders and that file names with `..` or `/` is not allowed. For example, check with [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath) that the file destination is not outside the folder you decided.

Comment: Please what do you mean by "unsafe PHP script" ?

Comment: I mean that you may have a PHP script which can be used to upload files. It may very well be the case that you *think* that script is safe but keep in mind that such scripts are often fooled if the uploaded filename contains anything you didn't expect (like a `/`).